# Accessing document files from dialog class in mfc, sdi

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new to mfc, so I don't know if I will explain my problem correctly but I'll try.

So I built a puzzle game in mfc, and I want to implement high score system. When the game is over, the dialog pops up, where you put your name, and name is written in the external txt file. So, I have Dialog class, where I implement stuff about putting in your name, and sending it to a txt file, but the problem is that I can't access the info about the score, which is stored in the ProjectDoc class, so I can't link the name of the player and the score.

So the question is how to access files from ProjectDoc class from dialog class.

Comment: Populate your custom dialog implementation with the information needed, from your view class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the score as parameter in the constructor of you dialog class:

```
CHighscoreDlg::CHighscoreDlg(int score)
{
    m_score = score;   // store in private class member variable
}

...
...
void CPuzzleView::EndGame() 
{
    CHighscoreDlg hs(GetDocument()->m_gamescore);
    hs.DoModal();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution offered by IInspectable and thomiel works great if you have one (or a few) parameter.

Another extreme would be to pass a pointer to the Document and let the Dialog pull whatever it needs out of it, but that would violate "need to know" policy.

I would suggest to define an interface (abstract class) IHighScoreProvider with required accessors, for example:

```
class IHighScoreProvider
{
public:
    virtual int GetGameScore() = 0;
    virtual std::string GetPlayerName() = 0;
};
```

Then derive your Document from it and implement those methods. And pass that interface pointer to your dialog.

Comment: Is there any reason to use an interface, not just define `GetGameScore()` and `GetPlayerName()` inside of the Document? Also, does *"pass that interface pointer"* mean something like `CmyDlg myDlg(GetDocument());` after making the Document derive from the interface?  - please let me know if I understood incorrectly.

Comment: The reason is to separate the relevant functions from your document's interface. For example, you can reuse that dialog with a different document, as long as it implements that interface. But I did mention in my answer that you could just pass the document around. I don't like it, because it exposes unrelated data of that document to your dialog, for no reason.